# During GRUB stage, Intel GPU-based system freezes if video is interrupted

Tags: grub, grub2, intel-graphics, debian-buster, debian-bookworm

I am in hell trying to figure out what is broken here.

I am running linux (both Debian Bookworm and Buster have been tested, but the problem happens presumably before the kernel loads).

I have a number of Intel-based Cincoze DA-1100 systems (Apollo Lake integrated graphics). When connected to an HDMI screen (via a DVI to HDMI adapter, or DVI/HDMI cable) these machines will freeze during the GRUB2 countdown timeout, if video is interrupted. The systems have a DVI video port.

To replicate this, I can run stock Debian 12.2 and as soon as the system beeps during POST, I can switch to a different HDMI source on the screen, and switch back. This interruption of video connection seems to crash GRUB2, it will stop counting down and the keyboard is unresponsive **except for CTRL-ALT-DEL.** That is to say, I can't use the arrow keys to scroll the menu, or do anything else in GRUB but restart it.

Setting an explicit resolution in grub.cfg does not fix anything.

Today I discovered that setting grub to TEXT mode, it seems like I am unable to replicate the freeze during the countdown...but the system will then freeze at "loading initial ramdisk", I suppose at the moment the kernel loads.

I would love to hear **any** theories or ways that I might be able to gather any logging or screen output on this. Since it happens prior to kernel loading (I think?) there is no journalctl or other dmesg logging that can help here.

I have been banging my head against the wall. Thanks anyone reading this.

Comment: Just asking : Why are you interrupting the video ?

Comment: These systems power digital signage; in one location we have 12 computers on 12 screens, and a power outage resulted in half of them being frozen during this GRUB2 timer, requiring manual intervention. I think when both screen and computer turn on it can generate this video interruption and cause the freeze.

Comment: Theory: when system first boots, it displays trivia such as that the disk is clean, and that could cause the interruption. Possible work-arounds: UPS for monitors (obviously, an expense), or connect to them with a unidirectional cable so operating system never knows the monitor is down (yet another expense).